# In excel VBA, how do I make my screen follow the image, wherever it goes?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to ask someone how to make the screen follow a image in VBA excel. (Image's top left cell: M12, Screen's top left cell: A1)

I have this table in Excel:

```
1    |A
2    |B
3    |C
4    |D
5    |E
6    |F
7    |G
8    |H
10   |I
11   |J
12   |K
13   |L
14   |M
15   |N
16   |O
...  |...
```

(That is not a code.)

To convert letters in the ranges to numbers so I can subtract them.

This is my VBA code:

```
Sub PicScroll()
'Variables
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Picpos As Range
Dim a As Shape

'Set variables
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Game")
Set a = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2")
Set Picpos = a.TopLeftCell

'Loop
Do Until 1 = 0

'Code
Appication.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Game").Range((ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").TopLeftCell.Row - 11) & _
 (Vlookup(ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").TopLeftCell.Column - L11.Column),Worksheets("CodeSheet").Range(I1:J77),2,False)), Scroll:=True

'End Loop
Loop
End Sub
```

CodeSheet is the worksheet that has the table shown on top.
Game is  the worksheet where the image(Picture 2) is.

I have some problem with the code in the *Application.Goto* line.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Game").Cells(a.TopLeftCell.Row - 11, _
        Number2Letter(a.TopLeftCell.Column - Range("L11").Column)), Scroll:=True
```

But before running, add this Function first at the bottom part of your module:

```
Function Number2Letter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
    Number2Letter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

The function converts column number into column letter. This eliminates the need for vlookup.

Comment: Thank you Wils Mils! I am so grateful that you can help me! :)

Comment: Do I need to cancel my whole code or just substitute your code into mine?

Comment: I need to cancel my whole code right? It just makes sense. Still, I do not know whether I am correct or not. Please answer me as fast as possible. Thank you!!!

Comment: like: `Sub Picscroll2()
    Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Game").Cells(a.TopLeftCell.Row - 11, _
        Number2Letter(a.TopLeftCell.Column - Range("L11").Column)), Scroll:=True

    Function Number2Letter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
    Number2Letter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    
    End Function
End Sub`

Comment: At the start, Picture 2 is at M12. But what happens when you move the picture to L11? (TopLeftCell of the picture) I think it will not work. "L11 - L11" is an error! Please help me.

Comment: Can we use an "If" ? Like if a.TopLeftCell.Row is less than 12, then code gives 1? So it will never go less than 1? Same with the Column?

Comment: Like: `If(a.TopLeftCell.Row<12,1)`

Comment: Add Loop until 1=0 (Forever) because 1 can never be 0?

Comment: The code works but I need to edit it a bit. (Add Loop)Your answer is accepted.